# How to find the definition of Computer Architecture terms in Compter Science?

Tags: computer-architecture

To find the meaning of computer architecture terms in Computer Science do I need to use a Computer Science book? Do I need to find the computer architecture terms in a Computer Science Dictionary or is there a another way of finding the computer architecture terms? If there is another way to find the terms please can you tell me? One example of a computer Architecture term is Memory cell. Another example of a Computer architecture term is Arithmetic Logic Unit.

Comment: Why not just google the terms you are interested in?

Comment: Googling the computer architecture terms helps but sometimes there are not many answers in google. If there are not many answers on the computer architecture terms how can I find the meaning of those terms. Do I need to use a computer science book,Computer science dictionary or is there another way of finding the meaning of computer architecture terms.  If there is another way please tell me?

Comment: How about a Computer Architecure book then? Keep in mind that usually at the end of the book there is an index with every term used in the book and the pages the term appears in so you should be ble to find what you are looking for easily

Answer (score 2):

Just use Google. For the specific examples you give, Wikipedia has detailed information: [memory cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_cell_(computing)), [arithmetic logic unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit). Any computer architecture textbook will also explain these terms.

The internet is full of resources about computer architecture. If Google doesn't give you a good answer, that means the term you were looking for doesn't exist and you used the wrong words.